# Is signal guaranteed to reach thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, locking

Lets say I have three threads, `T1, T2, T3`, a Lock `lock` and some Condition `cond` on a `Resource` resource.

`T1` acquires lock and now does `cond.await()` due to some condition and `T2` gets that lock and does `cond.signal()` and then proceeds to do `lock.unlock()`, but for a while, `T3` was also trying to acquire the lock so it is at the line of `lock.lock()`, what exactly happens?

Does `T2` re-get the lock or does `T3` get it or is it random based on scheudler?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), it specifically answers this question in the 3rd paragraph:

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional *fairness* parameter. When set `true`, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any particular access order.

Comment: OTOH, I think the unfair algorithm is lighter weight (faster & less memory) than the fair algorithm, and if fairness doesn't matter then an unfair lock is therefore preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a signal is issued one of the waiting threads will be removed and will be put back in entry set so that he can get a chance to run. In terms of signalAll all the waiting threads will be removed from the wait set and put back in entry set so that they get chance to run.

And yes the scheduler then decides which thread to pick from the entry set. In terms of fairness longest waiting will get the chance first.

Good explanation [here](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html)